# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on UIAlertController code = 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access, uialertcontroller

I have a view controller from where I am launching an `UIAlertController` on click of a Button. Below is my code:

```
- (IBAction)playOnlineURL:(UIButton *)sender {
[self launchPlayURLAlert];
}

- (void) launchPlayURLAlert{

NSString *defaultURLString = @“MY URL”;
UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: @"Play Online URL"
                                                                          message: @"Enter the URL"
                                                                   preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"Enter URL";
    textField.text = defaultURLString;
    textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
}];
[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Play" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[alertController textFields] firstObject].text];
    VideoPlayerVC *videoController = [[VideoPlayerVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"VideoPlayerVC"
                                                                       bundle:nil
                                                                          url:url];
    [self presentViewController:videoController animated:YES completion:nil];
}]];

[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil]];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

But, my app is crashing giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS.[image]

After trying lot of things, I finally changed the

```
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

to

```
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

in the above code and it started working.

So, my question is why passing **animated as YES** giving that crash?

Also, an interesting point to note is that if I reset my whole emulator and run the app with animated as YES then it is working for first few runs. After some X runs, it starts crashing.

Comment: It could be a memory issue if it is crashing after some X runs.

Comment: Even I had the same doubt but still can't understand why is it working when I pass animated:NO

Comment: It might be problem in your `videoController `. Please provide code of your `videoController `s `viewDidLoad()` and `viewWillApear()`

Comment: It is not the problem with my videoController because if I launch it directly on button click then there is no crash.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having what looks like a very similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41613598/uikit-crash-in-uiviewanimationstate-popanimationstate